# Can anyone make me understand what is the meaning of "stipulated" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"Those  who  have  already  applied  under  RTI  Act  2005  or  otherwise  may  apply afresh for the same along with required fee of Rs. 500/- before stipulated date. "

Can anyone make me understand what is the meaning of "stipulated" here?

I know that the meaning of stipulate is ' to state exactly what must be done'.

I can not understand what is the meaning of stipulated in that sentence.

Is the meaning stipulated here "specified"?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the meaning of stipulated here "specified"?

Yes. But you are required to conform to that requirement.

Comment: which requirement?@chasly from UK

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stipulate) **stipulate** means

> to specify as a condition or requirement (as of an agreement or offer)

This means that **to stipulate** can be used not only to define what must be done but also to define conditions relating to the actions. This means that the relavent authority (the one setting the conditions) can **stipulate**, for example, that application forms must be completed in block capitals using black ink. They can also **stipulate** that the form must be returned by a given date.

Your understanding of **to stipulate** is more restricted than its actual meaning. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the those who have applied before this Act supersedes prior rules or acts can reapply paying the new fee. They will be *grandfathered* in, if they do so **by** the stipulated date.

**grandfathered**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/grandfathered)

> To exempt (someone or something) from a new regulation that prohibits
>   or restricts something: